# Zend Framework: Помогите обернуть запрос

Tags: php_pdo, php, zend-framework, sql

День добрый комрады, у Zend_Db_Select есть такие методы как join(), joinleft() и т.д. Я толком пока не освоился как с ними работать, поэтому прошу помощи. Нужно правильно обернуть вот такой SQL-запрос:

```
SELECT sub. * , mail. * 
FROM `ListItem` AS list
JOIN `SubscriberData` AS sub ON list.SubscriberID = sub.id
JOIN `MailData` AS mail ON list.MailID = mail.id
JOIN `TagsListItem` AS tags ON list.id = tags.ItemID
WHERE list.UserID =666
AND tags.TagID =3
```

Помогите пожалуйста, а то пока оно работает через обычный $db->query(), а это не есть хорошо.

Answer (score 4):

Разобрался сам, вот конечный вариант запроса, обернутого в Zend_Db_Select:

```
$select = $db->select()
->from(array('list' => 'ListItem'), array())
    ->join(array('sub' => 'SubscriberData'), 'sub.id=list.SubscriberID', array('*'))
    ->join(array('mail' => 'MailData'), 'mail.id=list.MailID', array('*'))
    ->join(array('tags' => 'TagsListItem'), 'tags.Itemid=list.id', array())
        ->where('list.UserID=?', '666')
        ->where('tags.TagID=?', '3');
$result = $select->query()->fetchAll();
```

Comment: Вот он достойный ответ на свой же вопрос.

Если так бы люди на этом форуме продолжали пытаться и делать своими силами было бы круто.

просто +1 за то что справился сам!

Comment: Shrek, спасибо :) Просто для меня в данном случае выбора не было, как и во многих других :) Надо сделать, есть инструмент, у кого то получилось, есть документация... Значит нужно копать и разбираться, тем более мне самому это интересно и пригодится в будущем. :)